WooCommerce - why is the Variable not available in a later function?
We have a function in our child.php file that prefixes the Order Number with a "P".
see:   https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-add-prefix-or-suffix-to-woocommerce-order-number/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
   $prefix = 'P';
   $suffix = '';
   $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id . $suffix;
      debug_to_console( $new_order_id );    // print to console for testing
   return $new_order_id;
}

The console shows the value as e.g.  "P1234".
We have another later function that re-sequences the BACs (aka Direct Bank Transfer) data:
add_filter('woocommerce_bacs_account_fields','custom_bacs_fields');

function custom_bacs_fields( $new_order_id ) {
            debug_to_console( $new_order_id );    // Print to console for testing
global $wpdb;
$account_details = get_option( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts',
array( ...

But the console shows that $new_order_id no longer holds the Prefixed Order Number.
1 - How do I make the variable global, or otherwise make available?
2-  If global, does it still need to be passed into the function?
